# UDP hole punching fails with peers on LAN network with server

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

In implementing UDP hole punching for peer-to-peer UDP, I have come across some strange behavior:

When my server (S) is on the same LAN as my peer (P) with router (R)

Sending a UDP packet from P -> S, the server sees the packet as coming from R, with ip 192.168.1.1

**EDIT:**

This means that if I have 2 peers on LAN P1 and P2, I send packets from P1 and P2 to the server S.

They both appear to be connecting from 192.168.1.1. Completing the hole-punching, I send P1's ip and port to P2 and vice versa,

Then I send packets directly from P1 <-> P2, bypassing the server S. These packets fail to be delivered, because clearly the IP I have received is wrong - It is the router's LAN IP while I would expect a WAN IP.

However, sending UDP packets from S -> P1 or from S-> P2 is successful

Furthermore, everything works as expected on peers which NOT on the same LAN as the server.

1) Why does this happen?

2) How can I make it work in all situations?

```
LAN -> LAN, // fails
LAN -> WAN  // fails
WAN -> WAN  // works


void Client::sendStun()
{
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
UdpPacket packet(UdpPacket::STUN, id_);
udp::endpoint endpoint(address::from_string( serverIp_ ), serverPort_);
std::cout << "sending stun packet\n";
udpSocket_.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(&packet, sizeof(UdpPacket)), endpoint);
}

void Server::udpReceive()
{
    auto udpPacket = std::make_shared<UdpPacket>();
    auto endpoint = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint>();
    udpSocket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(&(*udpPacket), sizeof(UdpPacket)), *endpoint,
        [this, udpPacket, endpoint](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_recvd)
    {
        std::cout << "Received Udp Packet\n";
        if (!ec && bytes_recvd > 0)
        {
            if( udpPacket->type_ == UdpPacket::STUN)
            {
                endpoints_.insert( std::pair<unsigned, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint>(udpPacket->id_, *endpoint) );
                std::cout << "STUN: " << *endpoint << std::endl;
                udp_send_to( udpSocket_, UdpPacket(UdpPacket::MESSAGE, 0, "Server: STUN Received"), *endpoint ); // debug text
            }
        }

        udpReceive();
    });
}
```

Comment: what error (s) do you get?

Comment: @ piotrus I don't get an error per-se, but packets sent P2P simply fail to be delivered, ergo the UDP hole punching fails. The reason for this is that the IP is wrong - suppose we have the LAN to WAN case, and one peer is trying to connect to 192.168.1.1... this clearly wont work!

Comment: ok. please put your code

Comment: Sounds like you're looping client packets through a public address on your NAT device back to the server on the same private address space... a complicated scenario.  I'd suggest reading up on STUN to get an idea of how address discovery works in various arrangements.

Comment: I am using STUN to get the IP and port of each client

Comment: Added code showing how I get the peer ip/port

Comment: I don't use boost so I can't help from that standpoint.  A network diagram might help explain your problem, but presumably _your_ server is not the STUN server... that is generally in the public address space.  Essentially your client needs to utilize a public STUN server and detect that it's on the same private network as the target and then send packets directly to it.

Comment: Are there public stun servers I could use?